# My app not geting terminated after pressing the home button

Tags: iphone, ipad, memory-leaks

i am developing a ebook reader and i am facing the following issue. if i close the app and reopen , then it opens exactly in the same state as it used to be before closing. I suspect this may lead to a lot memory leaks. Is this the right way for the app to function? and will this behavior cause any memory leaks?? can anyone help me with this... I dint know what title to put on top.. Please apologize me if the title was misleading.. thank you.

Comment: This won't cause any memory leaks, unless of course your app is already leaking during runtime.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the expected behavior. After the introduction of iOS4, applications will keep their state between launches. Applications get terminated when the system is running low on memory, as the system terminates applications not recently used to free memory. This will not lead to memory leaks. For users running iOS3 pressing Home will terminate the application.

See [Understanding an Application’s States and Transitions](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/CoreApplication/CoreApplication.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH3-SW10) and [Multitasking](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/CoreApplication/CoreApplication.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH3-SW1) for more information.

Comment: hi mads.. Thanku for ur answer.. My ipad is running on 3.2. will it be same for 3.2 as well???

Comment: Yes. Multitasking was first available in iOS4, so an iPad running 3.2 will terminate applications when you press the home button.

Comment: But, in my iPad the app is not getting terminated and it is running on ios 3.2... Do u have some inputs for this mads?

Comment: Implement `applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application` in your app delegate with NSLog(@"App terminated"). Run your app and press home. Do you get the log output?

Comment: hey mads, i'v checked with NSLog and im not getting the log output.. I think the method (applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application) is not being called

Answer (score 3):

right appropriate code in delegate file

```
-(void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{//exit(0);
}
```

if nothing works write exit(0) in this method.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the BOOL key: "Application does not run in background" to your info.plist and set it to YES. Then your app should be terminated when you press the home button.